# Can I test if a facet value has been set?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, facet

Let's say I have a modal component with a header and footer facet, like:

```
<aura:attribute name="header" type="Aura.component[]" />
<aura:attribute name="footer" type="Aura.component[]" />

<header>
    <h2>{! v.header }</h2>
</header>

{! v.body }

<footer>
    {! v.footer }
</footer>
```

**Is there a way to test (or have a conditional for) if the footer has been set?**

I want to be able to not show the footer (or have some default content) if the consumer (parent component) does not include a footer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `aura:if` plus `empty()` would get you there:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.footer)}">
  
  Default Content
  
  <aura:set attribute="else">
    {!v.footer}
  </aura:set>

</aura:if>
```

`aura:if` causes an extra rendering cycle, but dynamically renders its content, which can save rendering/execution time.

`empty()` returns true if a value is undefined, null, empty string, or an empty array.

Comment: Perfect - thanks!